# Count time duration between two tags in a string in minutes

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string like below

```
%snd:   <00:00:00><00:02:20>
%snd:   <00:02:45><00:05:18>
%snd:   <00:05:49><00:09:84>
```

I want to count the time duration between these two tags in each line and show the sum of all the time difference in minutes.Should I have to convert them into proper javascript time object or is there any other direct way I can do it ?

Any help or hint will be highly appreciated.Thank You

Comment: Should you? That's your call. You could probably do the math yourself relatively easily or you can let the Date objects handle it for you.

Comment: You could find the second, minute, and hour (?) differences separately, then add them with *60, etc

Comment: Yes - convert to Date objects and get the difference.  It would be a lot easier than doing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your format is in `<minutes:seconds:milliseconds>` then pass the string inside <> tags to that function, it will give you time in minutes.Then you can apply your further logic.

```
 function timeToMinutes(time) {
    time = time.split(/:/);
    return time[0] + (time[1]/60) + time[2]/(60*100);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work correctly, it should return `time[0]*3600 + time[1]*60 + +time[2]` to return seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simpler to avoid Dates altogether. Convert the times to a common denominator, say seconds, do whatever mathematic operations you want on the seconds, then convert back to time at the end.

```js
/* Convert a string in h:mm:ss format to seconds
** @param {string} s - string in hh:mm:ss format
** @returns {number} - time converted to seconds
*/
function parseTime(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return b[0]*3600 + b[1]*60 + +b[2];
}

/* Convert a time in seconds to hh:mm:ss format
** @param {number} secs - seconds to convert
** @returns {string} - time in hh:mm:ss format
*/
function secondsToTime(secs) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  var sign = secs < 0? '-' : '';
  secs = Math.abs(secs);
  return sign + z(secs / 3600 | 0) + ':' + 
         z(secs % 3600 / 60 | 0) + ':' +
         z(secs % 60);
}

// Get time difference between 00:02:45 and 00:05:18
var diffInSeconds = parseTime('00:05:18') - parseTime('00:02:45');
console.log(secondsToTime(diffInSeconds))

// Deal with -ve difference between 00:05:18 and 00:02:45
var diffInSeconds = parseTime('00:02:45') - parseTime('00:05:18');
console.log(secondsToTime(diffInSeconds))

// Process a time pair (noting that 84 is likely an invalid value but is allowed)
var diff = '<00:05:49><00:09:84>'.match(/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/g).reduce((a,b)=>secondsToTime(parseTime(b) - parseTime(a)));
console.log(diff);
```